# Django rendering template in view class

Tags: python, django

In an attempt to further understand the Django framework, I am writing a small test case.  The app name is "login" and I have the following defined:

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import Index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', Index.as_view(), name='index')
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class Index(TemplateView):
    template_name = "/login/index.html"

    def get(self, request):
        render(request, self.template_name, None)
```

Running into a problem loading the page:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/
```

index.html is located in the login app folder:

```
/login/templates/login/index.html
```

What concepts am I missing here?

Comment: What if you *remove* the front slash, so `login/index.html`?

Comment: I did that and got the error: `The view login.views.Index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: that is because you forgot the `return` in `return render(..)`.

Comment: I also removed the get method in the class and it worked fine; however, what if I need to return a context to the page?  How is that accomplished?

Comment: you override `get_context_data`.

Comment: I sure did.  This is what I get for coding too early in the morning.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem, post an answer so I can upvote you.  Thaks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. you should not add a leading slash to the `template_name`; and
2. you forgot to specify a `return` statement:

```
class Index(TemplateView):
    template_name = "login/index.html"

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name, None)
```

That being said, a [**`TemplateView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView) actually already implements the render logic itself. It is used to omit the boilerplate logic.

If you want to add context data in a `TemplateView`, you need to override the [**`get_context_data(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data):

```
class Index(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'login/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['some_variable'] = 42
        return context
```

We here added an extra variable `some_variable` to the context that we render with the template.